# NSMutableString and setting up accessor methods Objective-C 2.0

Tags: accessor, objective-c-2.0

There is a copy attribute for synthesised accessor methods ex:

```
@property (copy) NSMutableString *string;
```

When assign using this setter method it seems to always call the copy method, even though I would like to create a mutable copy of what ever I assign to `string`, during assignment of the instance variable `string`.

Is this a know issue and are there any workarounds?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `@synthesize string` in your .m implementation file and instead write your own getter.

e.g.

```
- (NSMutableString *) string
{
    NSMutableString * stringToReturn = [NSMutableString stringWithString: someStringObject];
}
```

More information about properties (and what to do when you don't do `@synthesize`) can be found at:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html

p.s. the property name "string" may be confusing to anyone else who looks at your code down the road... I'd recommend changing that to be more program-specific